# Disable Print screen using Ajax control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can anyone please help me to disable print screen from a browser by using ajax control.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Nope, can't be done:

- special keys are hard to capture cross-browser
- even so, they can be remapped
- some screenshot tools are not triggered by keyboard
- there is no notification that a screenshot is being taken: not to the webpage, not to the application, not to the computer
- even so, the user could take a screenshot of a VM
- or even an actual digital photo of the screen.

So - **no, there is no way to do this.**

Comment: can we use JavaScript in the place of ajax control.

Comment: @Arun: 'can we use Javascript instead of Asynchronous Javascript And Xml'? That doesn't make sense; moreover, as I wrote, this is not dependent on language - there is no way to do this in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean that you want to stop the user from taking a screen shot? Sorry, you have no way of blocking that.

Comment: can we use JavaScript in the place of ajax control.

Comment: No, you have no way of controlling what the user does with his/hers system on that level. You can only control what the users loads in the browser. A screen shot has nothing to do with your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible becoz you can't control anything outside browser through web page

Comment: Even if you could, even a normal application is unable to prevent a screenshot (there was a heated discussion on this some two years back, I'll see if I can find it)

Comment: can we use JavaScript in the place of ajax control.